# boost odeint integration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost

Can someone please help me with the integration that I am trying to compute using the `boost` `odeint` library. This is what I have :

```
    double z0 = -1.6;
    double z1 = -1.0;
    double dz = (z1 - z0) / 100;
    double P(0.);
    size_t xx = boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(my_integrand, P, z0, z1, dz);
```

Where `my_integrand` is a function defined as (note, for the time being I have not defined the function computation fully as I want it to compile correctly first):

```
   void my_integrand(const double& P, double& dPdz, double z) { dPdz = 0.; };
```

I get the following errors at compile time:

```
3>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(68):error C2780: 'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(System,State &,Time,Time,Time)' : expects 5 arguments - 6 provided
3>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(72) : see declaration of 'boost::numeric::odeint::integrate'
3>..\..\test.cpp(36) : see reference to function template instantiation 'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate<void(__cdecl *)(const double &,double &,double),double,double>(System,State &,Time,Time,Time)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              System=void (__cdecl *)(const double &,double &,double)
3>  ,            State=double
3>  ,            Time=double
3>          ]
3>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(66) : see declaration of 'boost::numeric::odeint::integrate'
3>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(68): error C2783: 'size_t boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(System,State &,Time,Time,Time,Observer)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Value'
3>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(53) : see declaration of 'boost::numeric::odeint::integrate'
3>C:\boost\boost_1_61_0\boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate.hpp(68): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'boost::enable_if<has_value_type<State,boost::mpl::bool_<false>>::type,size_t>::type boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(System,State &,Time,Time,Time,Observer)'
3>          With the following template arguments:
3>          'System=void (__cdecl *)(const double &,double &,double)'
3>          'State=double'
3>          'Time=double'
3>          'Observer=boost::numeric::odeint::null_observer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the `integrate` line to

```
size_t xx = boost::numeric::odeint::integrate<double>my_integrand, P, z0, z1, dz);
```